# what the mean of 'super.prop = 3' and 'super.prop' in es6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, super, es6-class

```
class A{
}
class B extends A{
  constructor(){
    super();
    super.p = 3;
    console.log(super.p, this.p); // browser output 'undefined 3'
                                  // babel output 'undefined undefined' or '3 3'
  }
}
const b = new B();
```

in the browser and babel output different result, what is the mean of `super.p = 3`?

Comment: Read this [MDN on super](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super).

Comment: I have read it, and have not found anything helpful @jfriend00

Comment: `super.prop`, in my understanding, is equivalent to `Object.getPrototypeOf(this).prop`, `super()` is equivalent to `Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor.call(this)`, and `super.method()` is equivalent to `Object.getPrototypeOf(this).method.call(this)`

Comment: Seriously?  It gives specific examples and explanation for `super.prop`.  It would be more useful if you described what in that full description you don't understand rather than just dissing a whole article on the subject.

Comment: when super set a property, it's like `this.p = 3`，when super get a property, it's like `Object.getPrototypeOf(this).prop`

Comment: your understanding is the same as the code that Babel compiles， but it's not the same as the results that the browser is running@PatrickRoberts